# Ruby on Rails and simple_form display radio button collection horizontally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, simple-form

I'm trying to display a collection of radio buttons horizontally with Ruby on Rails and simple_form. Here is the field:

```
= f.input :familiar, label: false, collection: [ ['0', '0' ], ['1', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '4'], ['5', '5'], ['6', '6'], ['7', '7'], ['8', '8'], ['9', '9'], ['10', '10'] ], :as => :radio_buttons
```

I have found several SO questions pertaining this issue but none have worked for me, I will try to list all of the solutions I have tried:

```
.form-horizontal
.form-inline
:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'
```

None of these have made any difference for me. All suggestions are appreciated, I'm slightly concerned that this is so difficult to accomplish.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Nope, simple_form has become the bane of my existence. It is a popular but terribly documented gem that I wouldn't recommend to anyone.